# Force placement of sum operands over index

Tags: amsmath

I want to force the operands of a sum to be placed above an "extended" (longer than usual) index, instead of increasing the width of the sum (in the example, see the sums in (2), which are much wider than in (1), because of the different index). I need this for space reasons, the formula is bigger than in the MWE. Do you have any ideas how to achieve this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \text{\textbf{Total Cost }} 
    &= \sum_{m=1}^{55} 10,000 \cdot Z_m + 7,000 \cdot K_m \\
    &= \sum_{i \in \{m | Z_m = 1\}} 10,000 + \sum_{j \in \{k | K_m = 1\}} 
7,000
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try `\mathclap` from `mathtools`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `mathclap` from `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \text{\textbf{Total Cost }} 
    &= \sum_{m=1}^{55} 10,000 \cdot Z_m + 7,000 \cdot K_m \\
    &= \sum_{\mathclap{i \in \{m | Z_m = 1\}}} 10,000 + \sum_{\mathclap{j \in \{k | K_m = 1\}} }
7,000
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

`mathtools` loads `amsmath`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \textbf{Total Cost} % no trailing space inside braces
    &= \sum_{m=1}^{55} 10,000 \cdot Z_m + 7,000 \cdot K_m \\
    &= \sum_{\mathclap{i \in \{m\, | \, Z_m = 1\}}} 10,000 + \sum_{\mathclap{j \in \{k\, | \, K_m = 1\}}} 7,000 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: few seconds .. :)

Comment: Hi Sigur, I accepted @nidhin's answer, since he commented 3 minutes before posting his own answer and thus was a little faster. Thanks very much though for the quick and helpful answer, I appreciate the effort!

Comment: @ncw, no problem. Just pay attention in my comments on trailing spaces. Also, only `\textbf` is enough.

Answer (score 7):

A variant, with the `\smashoperator` command from `mathtools` – and some improvements with `siunitx`, so the comma separator in numbers doesn't add a space.

`\smashoperator` can take an optional argument, `[l]` or `[r]` which are equivalent to `\mathlap`  or `\mathrlap` respectively. I demonstrate it in a $3$rd equation:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\sisetup{group-digits = integer, group-separator={,}, group-minimum-digits = 4}
\begin{align}
  \textbf{Total Cost} % no trailing space inside braces
    &= \sum_{m=1}^{55} \num{10000} \cdot Z_m + \num{7000} \cdot K_m \\
    &= \smashoperator{\sum_{i \in \{m\mid Z_m = 1\}}}\num{10000} + \smashoperator{\sum_{j \in \{k\mid K_m = 1\}}} \num{7000} \\
    &= \smashoperator[r]{\sum_{i \in \{m\mid Z_m = 1\}}} \num{10000} + \smashoperator[l]{\sum_{j \in \{k\mid K_m = 1\}}} \num{7000}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]